# Flutter make container transparent with all items in it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have container that contains multiple text views, I want to reduce opacity of the container but also the all items in it.

```
background: kGreyColor.withOpacity(0.5)
```

When I change opacity of the container it only changes the background opacity but not the texts, I don't want to change all items' colors individually because it will take too much time.

Is there any way to achieve this in one go?

Comment: You can create a bool, or double and assign it to all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap your `Container` with `Opacity`

```
Opacity(
  opacity:.5,
  child: Container(),
)
```